# JL command in TASM works when it shouldn't

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

In my TASM program I need to compare a double word variable with a set of other double word variables, which are declared as this:

```
dd_buf dd 0
powers_of_10 dd 3B9ACA00h, 05F5E100h, 00989680h, 000F4240h, 000186A0h, 00002710h, 000003E8h, 00000064h, 0000000Ah
```

And I compare these values like this:

> I know that in this code bit I only compare first 16 bits of each variable

```
mov ax, word ptr dd_buf
mov bx, word ptr powers_of_10[di]
cmp ax, bx
jg greater
jl less
greater:
    mov dx, offset greater_output_hint
    call putstr
    call clrf
    jmp end
less:
    mov dx, offset less_output_hint
    call putstr
    call clrf
```

But when I run this program in Turbo Debugger, and check the values, I see that when ax register is set to FFFF, and bx is set to 03E8, after `cmp ax, bx` line my code jumps into `less`, as if AX is less than BX, when it is not!

What I was expecting, is that when ax is less than bx, after jl command it would jump into less section, and similar for case when ax is greater than bx.

I tried to do PUSHF and POPF commands before and after the instructions, but it didn't help. I also tried to compare ax and bx in two steps: firstly compare ah and bh, and then al and bl, but that didn't help also.

So, I am stuck. Googling this problem didn't bring anything, so I hope for your help.

Comment: "less" is signed less than, and `ffff` is negative one, which is less than 1000.

Comment: Note that besides the jg/jb/jl/ja issue explained in Mike Nakis' answer, the structure of your code is strange.  Are you aware, first of all, that if the two values are equal, your code would execute the `greater` code (since neither jump is taken)?  If that's what you want, then just delete `jg greater` altogether.  The `jl` (change to `jb`) will be taken if the comparison is "less", and if not then it is not taken and will fall through into `greater`, which you should then rename as `greater_or_equal` (though it doesn't actually need a label at all).

Comment: In general, to select between two options, you should only need one conditional jump.

Comment: Also, `cmp` like every other ALU instruction can take one memory operand.  So there is no need for the second `mov` to load `bx`; just do `cmp ax, word ptr powers_of_10[di]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *think* that when AX=0FFFFh, it is above 03E8h, but it really depends on whether you are comparing signed or unsigned numbers.
If 0FFFFh is treated as an unsigned number, it is 65535.
However, if 0FFFFh is treated as a signed number, is -1.
For signed comparisons, use JG/JL; but for unsigned comparisons, use JA/JB.